# jQuery - Why :first and :last work but not :nth-child(2) in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Please consider the following html snippet and its corresponding code with jQuery version 1.3.2:

```
<tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
    <td><select>
    <option value='0'>0</option>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
```

jQuery function:

```
function submitRoutesForm()
{
    data = new Array();
    $('#routes_table option:selected').each(function()
    {
        qty = $(this).val();
        if( qty != 0)
        {
            tmp = new Array();
            tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            tmp['route_id'] = tr.find('td:first').html();
            tmp['qty'] = qty;
            tmp['isChild'] = $(tr).find('td input:first').is(':checked');
            tmp['isInvalid'] = $(tr).find('td input:nth-child(2)').is(':checked');
            tmp['isSpecialDiet'] = $(tr).find('td input:last').is(':checked');
            data.push(tmp);
            console.log(tmp);
        }
    });

return false;
```

}

I could confirm that everything works expect the result for the second checkbox is always returning "false". It seems my selector :nth-child(2) doesn't work for some reason...

Many thanks in advance, I am stuck with this for a while :(

Comment: You variable "tmp" is not really being used as an array, so you should declare it as `var tmp = { };` - and **don't forget to declare all your local variables with the `var` keyword!!!**

Comment: Might be better to add value= attributes to the inputs in the html instead of relying on the code count elements and assign values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nth-child would be looking for a child of the td element and each one only has 1 child. You should use :eq(2) on the td. That will give you the index of the matching result set instead of a certain child.

```
$(tr).find('td input:eq(2)').is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't have a `td` with more than one `input`, so `nth-child(2)` won't find anything.

Comment: Ahhh.... I see the logic flaw in my code now... let me think how to change the selector expression now...

Comment: I can certainly add some unique identifier to each checkbox so that I can distinguish them by that; but what is the way to check the status of the three while leave the html as is?